# CheckBox: distinguish between box and label

Tags: javafx

I'm looking for a way to determine the exact source of a click on a CheckBox. I want to know if the click happened on the box itself or on the text.

event.getSource() doesn't help and I also tried some things on the CheckBoxSkin, but without success.

Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event.getTarget() might help you.

Comment: It seems I had a basic misunderstanding about target and source of an event.